# RVIZ Marker STL Mesh Color and Transparency Issues

Tags: ros, rviz, stl, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Has anyone been able to get STL meshes to properly display with the specified color and alpha values when generating the messages in roscpp and visualizing them in RVIZ?

For some reason, I can get the meshes to display but no matter how I change the color and alpha values, it stays the same solid gray color and opacity (I set mesh_use_embedded materials to false).

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271560/rviz-marker-stl-mesh-color-and-transparency-issues/) by [vkee](https://answers.ros.org/users/21470/vkee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

STL files are geometry only, no colors, textures, displacement maps, etc. are included. You can use Collada DAE files instead which include this kind of stuff. See [this nice answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/39959/stl-vs-dae/) for more details.

---

Originally posted by [Managarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/32102/managarm/) with karma: 28 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
It was only implied, but I think @vkee is publishing [Marker](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker)s messages, and trying to use STLs as mesh resources.